# How can I show that these two sets have the same cardinal?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Let ${\{A_i\}}_{i \in I}$ be a family of sets, where $\# A_i < \infty$ for all $i \in I$ and $\# I = \infty$. How can I show that
$$
\# \left(\bigcup_{i \in I} A_i\right) = \# I?
$$

Comment: You need further assumptions. For example, if all the sets $A_i$ are equal. then the union is finite. On the other hand, if, for example, you require the sets $A_i$ to be pairwise disjoint, then the claim is true.

Comment: Well, pairwise disjoint and non-empty

Comment: What is $\infty$? I've been doing set theory for the better part of a decade now, I don't know that cardinal.

Comment: @AsafKaragila +1. However I think that it's acceptable to have $\infty$ stand for "not finite".

Comment: @Arnaud: No, it's not.

Comment: @AsafKaragila I agree that the last equality in the OP requires a more careful treatment, but in general there are cases where "not finite" is really all you want to say. Also, it is common to write $<\infty$ to imply "finite". As soon as everyone understands what you mean, it's fine.

Comment: @Arnaud: Evrybdy shld aslo undrstnad me heer. Is that also fine? We have rules for languages for a reason.

Comment: @Munchhausen Instead of "pairwise disjoint and nonempty" maybe you can get by with just "distinct": $A_i\ne A_j$ whenever $i\ne j.$

Comment: @AsafKaragila Right. So what is the proper symbol to denote "finite" or "not finite"?

Comment: @Arnaud: Well, "not finite". If you insist, since the axiom of choice is always involved, $<\aleph_0$ or $<\omega$ would both be acceptable.

Comment: @ArnaudMortier "$\vert X\vert\not<\aleph_0$," if one insists on avoiding words.

Comment: @NoahSchweber I can see one flaw picturing myself teaching this way: students need a symbol for this long before they learn transfinite cardinal numbers.

Comment: @Arnaud: I think that we need to uproot this notion of "everything needs a symbol". Sure, terminology and symbols can help when you try to be succinct, but at least "finite" and "infinite" are sufficiently clear and relatively short. Insisting on using symbols is wrong on several levels here.

Answer (score 1):

> **Claim**: Given $I$ well-ordered and non-empty, and cardinals $\{\kappa_i\}_{i\in I}$ such that for any $i\in I,$ we have that either $\kappa_i$ is finite or an aleph, if $I$ or some $\kappa_i$ is infinite, then $$\sum_{i\in I}\kappa_i=\max\left\{|I|,\sup_{i\in I}\kappa_i\right\}.$$

**Proof** First, note that $\sup_{i\in I}\kappa_i$ is a well-orderable cardinal--in particular, it is the least such cardinal that is $\geq\kappa_i$ for all $i\in I$. Let $f:I\to|I|$ be a bijection, and define $g:\bigcup_{i\in I}\kappa_i\times\{i\}\to|I|\times\sup_{i\in I}\kappa_i$ by $g(\alpha,i)=\langle f(i),\alpha\rangle$. Since $f$ is a bijection, then $g$ is an injection from $\bigcup_{i\in I}\kappa_i\times\{i\}$ into $|I|\times\sup_{i\in I}\kappa_i$, and so $\sum_{i\in I}\kappa_i\leq|I|\cdot\sup_{i\in I}\kappa_i.$

Since it can be shown that, for any well-orderable cardinals $\alpha$ and $\beta$ with at least one of them infinite, we have $\alpha\cdot\beta=\max\{\alpha,\beta\},$ then we have $|I|\cdot\sup_{i\in I}\kappa_i=\max\bigl\{|I|,\sup_{i\in I}\kappa_i\bigr\},$ and so $$\sum_{i\in I}\kappa_i\leq\max\bigl\{|I|,\sup_{i\in I}\kappa_i\bigr\}.$$

Now, clearly, $I\to\bigcup_{i\in I}\kappa_i\times\{i\}$ given by $i\mapsto\langle 0,i\rangle$ is defined (since each $\kappa_i>0$) and injective, so $|I|\leq\sum_{i\in I}\kappa_i$. Define $h:\bigcup_{i\in I}\kappa_i\times\{i\}\to\bigcup_{i\in I}\kappa_i$ by $h(\alpha,i)=\alpha$. Clearly, $h$ is surjective, and since its domain is well-orderable, then it can be shown that there is an injection from $\bigcup_{i\in I}\kappa_i$ into $\bigcup_{i\in I}\kappa_i\times\{i\}$. Since $\sup_{i\in I}\kappa_i=\bigcup_{i\in I}\kappa_i$ by definition, then $\sup_{i\in I}\kappa_i\leq\sum_{i\in I}\kappa_i$. $\Box$

---

At this point, I invoke the Axiom of Choice.* As your set $I$ is infinite, but of unspecified cardinality, we can't guarantee that it is well-orderable without assuming that *all* sets are well-orderable, which is a form of AC. This is also enough to ensure that each of your finite (so well-orderable) sets $A_i$ can have a well-ordering chosen for each of them via choice function, and that $\aleph_0\le|I|.$ Thus, we have the following

> **Corollary**: $$\left|\bigcup_{i\in I}A_i\right|=|I|.$$

**Proof**: Note that the left-hand side is simply $\sum_{i\in I}|A_i|$, by definition and by the fact that they are pairwise-disjoint. Moreover, by the fact that each $A_i$ is finite, while $I$ is infinite, we have $$\sup_{i\in I}|A_i|\le\aleph_0\le|I|,$$ and hence, applying the Claim, we have $$\left|\bigcup_{i\in I}A_i\right|=\sum_{i\in I}|A_i|\le\max\left\{|I|,\sum_{i\in I}|A_i|\right\}\leq\max\bigl\{|I|,\aleph_0\bigr\}=|I|.\Box$$

---

*If you're taking the Axiom of Choice for granted, then we can also adjust the Claim as follows:

> Given $I$ non-empty and cardinals $\{\kappa_i\}_{i\in I},$ if $I$ or some $\kappa_i$ is infinite, then $$\sum_{i\in I}\kappa_i=\max\left\{|I|,\sup_{i\in I}\kappa_i\right\}.$$

Comment: I find it odd that you use "non-$\emptyset$". It is *literally* shorter to type "non-empty" and even shorter if you opt for "nonempty". It's even clearer to people who read this and for some reason are unfamiliar with the notation for the empty set... :P

Comment: Fair point. The brevity (plus my aforementioned repeated exposure) is why I originally got used to saying "non-$0," and since I was largely working with ordinals and cardinals at the time, the habit just settled in.